# isset checkbox return null code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried to get the value to my checkbox(1 = checked or 0 = unchecked) in this code(this is my views in my Code Igniter):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Visible" class="text" value="1"
                <?php $visible = isset($_POST['Visible'])? '1' : '0';?>/>
```

My questions are :

1. Can someone explain to me why the result of $visible is always NULL?
2. What is the function of `value="1"` in this case?i was searching this case but people just says that we always need to add the value.
3. How to get the right value?(1 = checked or 0 = unchecked)

Thank you, and i know this is a very simple question but it keep gives me some errors since yesterday @_@

**This is the bigger part of the code :**
Add function is for save(in controller) :

```
function add(){

    $data['title'] = 'Tambah Category baru';
    $data['action'] = site_url('category/add');
    $data['link_back'] = anchor('category/index/', 'Back to Category list', array('class'=>'back'));

    //bedakan add/update
    $data['validate'] = 'add';

    $this->_set_rules();
    //run validation
    if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
        $data['message'] = '';

        $data['title'] = 'Add new Category';
        //$data['message'] = '';
        $data['category']['ID_category'] = '';
        $data['category']['ID_user'] = '';
        $data['category']['Nama_category'] = '';
        $data['category']['Description'] = '';
        $data['category']['Visible'] = '';
        $data['link_back'] = anchor('category/index/', 'Lihat daftar Category', array('class'=>'back'));

        $this->load->view('category_form_v', $data);
    }

    else{
        //save data
        $category = array('ID_category'=>$this->input->post('ID_category'),
        'ID_user'=>'TESTING USER',
        'Nama_category'=>$this->input->post('Nama_category'),
        'Description'=>$this->input->post('Description'),
        'Visible'=>($$this->input->post('Visible') !== false ? '1' : '0'),
        'tgl_buat '=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

        $ID_category = $this->category_m->save($category);

        $this->validation->ID_category = $ID_category;

        redirect('category/index/add_success');
    }
}
```

And my HTML code(in Views) :

```
<td valign="top">Visible<span style="color:red;">*</span></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="Visible" class="text"/>
```

Comment: You have unclosed input, check `/>`, please.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to copy that part :D Thanks!

Comment: If it's unchecked, the superglobal `$_POST` won't have any element with the key `Visible`. On the other hand, if it IS checked, then `$_POST` will have an element with the key `Visible` which holds the value of the string `1`.

Comment: @KemalFadillah Thanks :D But i when i tried to check it, it still give me a NULL value

Comment: That's because you didn't set any value for the input element. Also, I noticed you asked a lot of questions regarding CodeIgniter and PHP within the last few days. You might want to read some good tutorials on the internet or buy some books to get you started instead of just asking questions how to fix the errors you're facing with. Then, when you're really stuck, come back here and ask a question.

Comment: I have tried to input the value="1",  its still give me NULL in Database @_@
Yes i do aware for that, but i have a deadline so its impossible for me to learn in tutorial anymore (btw i have watched thenewboston tuts and read some ebooks before)
Thanks :D

Comment: Your current code shouldn't produce `NULL` in the database. The issue's probably in your model method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [input library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) instead.

Specifically the post function

```
$visible = ($this->input->post('Visible') !== false ? 1 : 0);
```

---

### Update after question update

```
function add(){

    $data['title'] = 'Tambah Category baru';
    $data['action'] = site_url('category/add');
    $data['link_back'] = anchor('category/index/', 'Back to Category list', array('class'=>'back'));

    //bedakan add/update
    $data['validate'] = 'add';

    $this->_set_rules();
    //run validation
    if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
        $data['message'] = '';

        $data['title'] = 'Add new Category';
        //$data['message'] = '';
        $data['category']['ID_category'] = '';
        $data['category']['ID_user'] = '';
        $data['category']['Nama_category'] = '';
        $data['category']['Description'] = '';
        $data['category']['Visible'] = '';
        $data['link_back'] = anchor('category/index/', 'Lihat daftar Category', array('class'=>'back'));

        $this->load->view('category_form_v', $data);
    }

    else{
        //save data
        $category = array('ID_category'=>$this->input->post('ID_category'),
        'ID_user'=>'TESTING USER',
        'Nama_category'=>$this->input->post('Nama_category'),
        'Description'=>$this->input->post('Description'),
        'Visible'=>($this->input->post('Visible') !== false ? '1' : '0'),
        'tgl_buat '=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

        $ID_category = $this->category_m->save($category);

        $this->validation->ID_category = $ID_category;

        redirect('category/index/add_success');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :D
I tried your way with this code : 'Visible'=>($$this->input->post('Visible') === true ? '1' : '0')
But it gives me an fatal error : Call to a member function post() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ciGlassProject\application\controllers\category.php

Comment: Also, you don't want === true, the reason you use !== false is because the function returns false if the key is not set, it does not return true if it is, actually in your example it would return `1` so the code you want is `'Visible'=>($this->input->post('Visible') !== false ? '1' : '0')`

Comment: sory the double $$ is just the copy-paste mistake. I have tried your code but the error is still the same :D Thanks!

Comment: Also, try adding a value to your checkbox as well.

Comment: Yes i used exactly same code like yours, and i also try to add a value="1", but the fatal error is still showing 
Thanks :D